# How do CAS identify the second application?

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

I do have 2 web applications, one written in Rails and the other in PHP, which requires SSO. I understand that when the user attempts to use one of the apps, the user will have to login. Once the user have been authenticated and then the user opens the second app in the browser. How does CAS identify that the user have already logged in? Some kind of authentocation is to be submitted to CAS server, who does this and where is this info stored after the first time authentication with the first app.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wanted to make your two apps be able to SSO, then made them become CAS clients (CASifying them). For information how to do that visit here: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Official+Clients

If you wanted to know how CAS works, I would suggest to read this: http://www.jasig.org/cas/cas2-architecture

In short, CAS stores a cookie in your browser the first time you log-in, therefore it will send straight to the second app when you access the second app.

Thai

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Answer.

I have found out that Ruby has gem named Casio (http://rubygems.org/gems/casino) to do this, which is handy.